# Путь к сайту подводится неверно vue & nginx

Tags: vue.js, nginx, веб-сервер, config, vds

Долго ломал голову почему у меня по ip лежит правильная версия сайта, а по домену нет!
И тут я обнаружил в network, что по каким-то причинам когда я захожу по домену, то нжинкс стучится в корневую папку проекта, а когда я захожу через ip, то он стучится правильно (в папку dist)
У меня есть только один конфиг называющийся findir.store и каким-то образом через него сайт работает и по ip и по домену.
Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему с путём когда открываю по домену

Также прикладываю скрин network (слева правильный, справа нет) где видно что список подключённых css, js и др. файлов отличаются...хотя это один и тот же проект.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
также nginx
[image: nginx]

Comment: подводится под что?

Comment: А Вы Nginx перезагружали хоть? Конфиг у Вас правильный вроде

Comment: да, нжинкс рестартал, пробовал открывать инкогнито
Всё равно не то(